# All UITabBarItem icons are tinted when app starts

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tint

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 items, and when the app starts, all the items' icon appear tinted, instead of having one tinted and the other two greyed out:

[image]

After I navigate through the tabs, they start to behave correctly. Why is this happening?

Comment: I use a storyboard. Tabs' names and icons are set on it, not on code.

Comment: set this property manually "selectedIndex" and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line into your App Delegate

`[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had included `[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];` previously, because I wanted to set it as "global tint". Now I've figured out that was the problem. I replaced with your suggestion and it worked. Thanks!